# Mocha Chai Tests Pass buth shouldn't

Tags: mocha.js, chai

Here's the current test:

```
  describe('/POST Register Page', function() {
    it('it should register new user', function(/*done*/) {
      chai.request(server)
        .post('/auth/register')
        .send(new_user_data)
        .end(function(res) {
          expect(res).to.have.status(2017);
          // done();
        })
    })
  })
```

The last I checked, there's no http code as `2017`, however, it still passes:

```
Registration
    Get register page
GET /auth/register 200 6.989 ms - 27
      ✓ it should get register page
    /POST Register Page
      ✓ it should register new user


  2 passing (147ms)
```

I want to simply post something, then get a response back, and play with the response.

If I include the `done()`, I get the timeout error:

```
1) Registration /POST Register Page it should register new user:
     Error: Timeout of 3000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I can't get anything to work, as for whether wrong or right, the tests pass.

Although this get request is passing as expected:

```
  describe('Get register page', function() {
    it('it should get register page', function(done) {
      chai.request(server)
        .get('/auth/register')
        .end(function(err, res) {
          expect(err).to.be.null;
          expect(res).to.have.status(200);
          done();
        })
    })
  })
```

I'm new at this mocha-cum-chai-chai-http thing, and the experience so far is weird.

Thanks.

Comment: If you plan to not use the `done` callback (and if you have Promises you shouldn't) then just return `chai.request`. Just make sure you have the [`Promise` feature](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http#dealing-with-the-response---promises) enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Your POST request is probably taking longer than 3 seconds to complete, therefore mocha throws the timeout error.

You can try setting the timeout to a larger value like:

```
describe('/POST Register Page', function() {
  // timeout in milliseconds
  this.timeout(15000); 

  // test case
  it('it should register new user', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/auth/register')
      .send(new_user_data)
      .end(function(res) {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        done();
      })
  })
})
```

With some trial, you can figure out an optimum value of timeout to set in your tests.

When you don't use the `done()` callback, mocha simply skips the assertions without waiting for the actual response to arrive. Since the assertions in `.end()` block never get executed, mocha passes the test as it faces no assertions. I had faced something similar when I first started out with TDD, which I learned about the hard way.

[Reference](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http#caveat):

> Because the end function is passed a callback, assertions are run
>   asynchronously. Therefore, a mechanism must be used to notify the
>   testing framework that the callback has completed. Otherwise, the test
>   will pass before the assertions are checked.